# Show menu/div onclick or onmouseover not the easy way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a menu that can collapse:

- If you click on a button div the menu shows and stays even if you hover the button div.
- If you click again on the button div the menu hides.
- When the menu is hiding onmouseenter or mouseover it shows onmouseleave or mouseout 
  it's hiding.

I can't make this happen, this is my code:

```
        $(function() {
        $('#arrow').bind('mouseenter', function(){
            if($('#hoofdmenu').attr("class") == "show"){
            $('#hoofdmenu').addClass("class", "mousehide"); 
            $('#hoofdmenu').hide();
            }
            else 
            {
            $('#hoofdmenu').removeClass("class", "mousehide");  
            $('#hoofdmenu').addClass("class", "mouseshow");
            $('#hoofdmenu').show();
            }
        });

        $('#arrow').bind('click',function(){
            if ($('#hoofdmenu').attr("class") == "show"){
            $('#hoofdmenu').attr("class", "hide");  
            $('#hoofdmenu').hide();
            }
            else
            {
            $('#hoofdmenu').attr("class", "show");  
            $('#hoofdmenu').show(); 

            }
        });

     });
```

Someone can help me with this problem?
Kind regards,
Frank

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to add special classes for this? You can use the hide() and show() function for clicks and the mouseOver() and mouseOut() functions for the mouse hover.

[Check this out for more](http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-menu/#)

Edit: For some reason I cannot load jquery.com to point out the right pages

Comment: No it's not like accordion. It's a menu that slides in sorry maybe I was not obvious.

Comment: Still the code used in accordion (or in the post below) can help you out. The principle stays the same: hiding and showing something on a mouseclick or mousehover.

Answer (score 0):

Using attr() and classes a lot is pretty slow, since a DOM reflow is issued each time. Also, make sure to cache elements. We can speed things up a bit doing this:

```
$(function(){
    var menu = $('#menu'),
        arrow = $('#arrow'),
        isOpen = false;

    arrow.hover(function(){
        if(isOpen) return;

        if(menu.is(':visible'))
            menu.hide();
        else
            menu.show();
    });
    arrow.click(function(){
        if(isOpen)
            menu.hide();
        else
            menu.show();

        isOpen = !isOpen; // shift bool
    });
});
```